# Not able to get access token from reddit api through python requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests, reddit

I am trying to get access token for a webapp i created on reddit using oAuth using standard code based flow mentioned in the reddit API documentation but I'm getting invalid grant error
Im sharing the code

```
client_id='YOaekKn0YD409Pru8wadRg'
secret='WtSYCHzjlXQTYokP3aQMOVQm9lXpkg'
import requests
data={'client_id':client_id,'response_type':'code','state':'xoxo4','redirect_uri':'https://www.google.com/','scope':'read ','duration':'permanent'}
print(response.url)
```

The URL I get from here is used to get the code for getting the access token,but it is not being generated it is showing error even after passing all the required parameters
the code for that is given below:-

```
code='7XY6Hvv95a847m-Hf3A5qqIEfmm24g#_'
data={'grant_type':'authorization_code','code':code,'redirect_uri':'https://www.google.com/'}
a=requests.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',auth=(client_id,secret),data=data,headers={'User-Agent':'shuklbh'})
print(a.status_code)
print(a.text)
```

In the text ideally it should show the access token but it is showing something like this

```
200
{"error": "invalid_grant"}
```

200 verifies that API call is successful.
I'm not able to identify the mistake.Can somebody please help me??

Comment: Is that the real client_id and secret? Change them for fakes ASAP to post here on SO, and rotate your credentials!

Comment: oh no! definitely don't show that here

Comment: I'd suggest `client_id=...`- it gets the point across anyway

Answer (score 1):

The best way to work with Reddit API on Python (coming from someone that worked with it in the past) is to use the praw (Python Reddit API Wrapper). Their doc talks about authentication [here](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/authentication.html). It as simple as:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="FAKEN3DSbt0zor",
    client_secret="FAKEj7HNh8kwg8e5t4m6KvSrbTI",
    password="fakewevlfo00esyy",
    user_agent="script by guy on SO",
    username="guy_on_so",
)
```

This will retrieve a session, you can confirm you got a session by calling `reddit.user.me()` for example.

Comment: Actually, I am learning to use different kinds of APIs using the requests library. So if you could help me with that  it would be really helpful,because, you see that I cannot use a separate library for different kinds of API's,this library I use because it is general for most API's